# Не удается запустить проект с помощью conda

Tags: github, gitlab, anaconda, conda

Пытаюсь запустить данный проект https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.paper.deep_pix_bis_pad.icb2019

Пытался установить на `anaconda 2016` и `anaconda 2022`

Версия OS `ubuntu 21.10`

Делал все как описано в README. Например, ввожу `conda env create -f environment.yml`, но получаю примерно такие ошибки:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libblitz==1.0.1 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for libblitz==1.0.1`.

**environment.yml**

```
  - pip:
    - dask==0.18.1
    - torch==0.4.1
    - cyvlfeat
    - dlib==19.7
    - ipdb==0.11
    - libblitz==1.0.1
    - libmatio=1.5.11
    - libsvm==3.22
    - menpo==0.8.1
    - menpofit==0.5.0
    - openh264==1.7.0
    - vlfeat==0.9.21
    - zc.buildout==2.11.2
    - zc.recipe.egg==2.0.5
```

Уже задавал подобный вопрос здесь, но решение так и не нашли https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73275096/how-to-run-project-with-the-help-conda

Comment: если не продакшн, то, может, сделать бэкап, перекреститься и поменять `libblitz==1.0.1` на `libblitz>=1.0.1`?) 1.0.2 вроде есть в репозитории: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libblitz

Comment: Тогда вот так  ```Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libblitz>=1.0.1 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for libblitz>=1.0.1```

Comment: `conda search -c conda-forge libblitz` что выдает?

Comment: ```libblitz                     0.10                          0  conda-forge     
                             1.0.2                h9c3ff4c_0  conda-forge     
                             1.0.2                h9c3ff4c_1  conda-forge     
                             1.0.2                h9c3ff4c_2  conda-forge     
                             1.0.2                h9c3ff4c_3  conda-forge```